# Bootstrap 4 auto layout except of small

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there possible to stack elements on each other (col-12) on small device, but use auto-layout for all bigger screens? An example mentioned below does not work. I do not know how many columns I will render (1-6) so cannot "calculate the class" in advance.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the auto

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">Column 3</div>
</div>
```